# Select and run individual test cases from CCNet

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I am about to configure our C#.NET source code to have automated building mechanism using CCNET. Im wondering whether I can configure CCNet such a way that I can select individual test or subset of test from an assembly and run them. If it is possible to do so, could you please guide me in configuring the same.

Please let me know if further information is needed and thank you in advance.

Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the [CategoryAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2) in your tests and then [specify it in the command that run the tests](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.5).

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  public class SuccessTests
  {
    [Test]
    [Category("Long")]
    public void VeryLongTest()
    { /* ... */ }
}
```

and then:

`nunit-console myassembly.dll /include:Long`

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the response. I have tried decorating Category attribute to few test cases and used <includedCategories> tag in ccnet.config file to include/exclude certain test cases. But, this is static providion.

But, Im looking for any other way where we can add a plug in in CCNET dashboard so that user can select a set of test cases to be run and get the selected test case results instead of running all of the test cases.

Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: Does this guide help? http://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2008/06/15/cruisecontrolnet-tutorial-part-2/#ccnettutnunittask

Comment: CC.Net is "dumb" in that is can only call/execute abilities that exist with the sub-tool (NUnit for example).  So if you can call it from the command-line, you can make it work with CC.NET.

Comment: But this answer is the best answer.  "Category" is how to include/exclude tests via NUnit.  And CC.NET can only do what the NUnit-Console.exe does already.